# Limit function to only running once (even if called multiple times) per 5 minutes

Tags: node.js, api, express, queue, limit

I have a function within my Express/Node API that essentially does a 'roundup' of data after certain actions are performed.

Users can perform actions (call to an API route) multiple times in short intervals. After this API route is called, the roundup function is called. I don't want it called every time though; just once every 5 minutes for example (though still triggered by the API action).

I really only care about the *final* call (as roundup uses that info to update other data, but earlier ones are fine, as long as they are distanced apart (and not consecutive).

Basically what I want is:
- even if the roundup function is called 20 times in, let's say 5 minutes, only run once

I've tried using lodash's debounce function for this; but it's still not working properly for me.

For example... (not real code, but base structure)

```
function roundup(){
// Do something here, but it's DB intensive and we really only care about the *final call* so only want it to run sometimes (?)

}

// API Route which will call roundup when finished
app.post('/list/join', (req, res) => {
   // my lodash attempt 
   let debounced_roundup = _.debounce(roundup, 300000);
   debounced_roundup();
});
```

I expect the debounce to hold up calling the roundup function until after the delay (300000), but because the API calls are individual, I don't think they are triggering the debounce as I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the debouncer *outside* of your post method, or else you're creating a new, separate instance of the debouncer each time your API is called, which will know nothing of the previous triggerings.

```
let debounced_roundup = _.debounce(roundup, 300000);

// API Route which will call roundup when finished
app.post('/list/join', (req, res) => {
   debounced_roundup();
});
```

Comment: Yikes, can it be so simple!? You are a gem, thanks a bunch. Will give this a go.

Comment: By the way, if you don't want the execution of `roundup` to keep being postponed indefinitely by each new invocation, you might want to consider `throttle` instead of `debounce`, which will run no more than once every five minutes, but will also at run least that often if it's being triggered more frequently than once per five minutes.

Comment: I actually originally used throttle, but debounce is working better for me I think. It's not time sensitive at all, and also just need the *last* update; so the later the better.

This worked great by the way. I can't believe I didn't get this before, so simple!

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, quick question for you.

If I wanted this to be a 'session specific' debounce; how would I go about that? 
I have access to the req.session in the API post route, but how could use debounce calling the roundup function only from that same session?

Right now it seems like it will debounce ANY request; which isn't what I want... The roundup function has some user specific info in there. 

Let me know if that makes sense....

Comment: Assuming you have some sort of session ID, you can create a new debouncer for each session (remembering to clean it up when the session ends), then use the session ID as a key to store each debouncer in an object or a map, then look up the debouncer by ID at each API call.